# sending outlook meeting request through asp.net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, outlook

How do I sending meeting request through .net web application?

Comment: Hi, 
I think you options are;
1.create and ICS file on the server that the user downloads. (many event site do this).

2.If you have exchange you can use Exchange DAV or EWS to create an send meeting request. (this it probally the easiest)

So what do you have in your ENV what kind of experiance are you looking for? is this just for outlook users etc.

Answer (score 2):

As 76mel suggested an ICS file will create an Outlook calendar event (or for any calendar application that supports iCal) - there pretty simple - just need to write a text file with an ICS extension and a mime type of "text/calendar":

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID: YourAppName
METHOD: PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20100401T000000Z
DTEND:20100401T000000Z
LOCATION:Somewhere
UID:MeetingId
DTSTAMP:20100330T225528Z
DESCRIPTION:Meeting Title
SUMMARY:Meeting Description
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: be sure to use an ashx handler to output the ics file. Lots of examples of outputting images and zip files on the internet.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not using ASP, but I am making a separate application (not a plug-in) for setting up meetings.   Do you recommend any particular site for a tutorial on these "ICS files"?